# Copying generic values to unsigned char array and copying back in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class in C++ that represents a buffer where I can store `unsigned char`. I have two methods, one the add generic values using templates and another to retrieve the values. When I am trying to retrieve the values I am getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I am using `memcpy` If I change to use `std::copy(value, value, _valueChar);` I get other errors: `error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<int>’`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class SkinnyBuffer {
private:
    unsigned char *_valueChar;
    std::size_t _sizeChar;
public:
    SkinnyBuffer();
    SkinnyBuffer(std::size_t size);
    ~SkinnyBuffer();
    void clean();

    template<typename T>
    void addValue(T value) {
        if (_valueChar != nullptr) {
            delete[] _valueChar;
        }
        // _sizeChar = n; // assume _size is a field
        // _valueChar = new unsigned char[_sizeChar];
        // std::copy(value, value, _valueChar);
        memcpy(_valueChar, &value, sizeof(value));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void addValue(std::size_t offset, T value) {
        if (_valueChar != nullptr) {
            delete[] _valueChar;
        }
        // _sizeChar = n; // assume _size is a field
        // _valueChar = new unsigned char[_sizeChar];
        // std::copy(value, value + offset, _valueChar);
        memcpy(_valueChar + offset, &value, sizeof(value));
    }

    unsigned char *getValue() {
        return _valueChar;
    }
};
#include "SkinnyBuffer.h"

SkinnyBuffer::SkinnyBuffer() {
}

SkinnyBuffer::SkinnyBuffer(std::size_t size) {
    _sizeChar = size;
    _valueChar = new unsigned char[_sizeChar];
}

SkinnyBuffer::~SkinnyBuffer() {
}

void SkinnyBuffer::clean() {
    _valueChar = new unsigned char[_sizeChar];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int value = 50;
    int offset = sizeof(value);
    SkinnyBuffer b(offset);
    b.addValue(value);

    int dValue;
    memcpy(&dValue, b.getValue(), offset);
    std::cout << dValue << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "copying"? Not "coping".
Also, always worth running code in a debugger to see what's going on - I think your errors would be self-evident if you did that. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `addValue` you explicitly delete the `_valueChar` buffer. Then *the next line along* you write into the deleted buffer. What did you expect this code to do?

This is the first of many issues in your code regarding memory management.

Just use a `std::vector` and as long as its big enough you wont have any of those issues.

Comment: I have the same code using vector and I want to use char array.